# В какую панель выводить FTP, TotalCommander

Tags: файлы, ftp, файловая-система, totalcommander

Для закачки файлов на сервер я использую TotalCommander, и столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть Ftp запись. Когда я захожу в неё и идёт соединение по Ftp то оно открывается то в правой панели то в левой. Видимо это зависит от того на какой панеле я нахожусь сейчас.
Обычно я стараюсь заходить так что бы справа была панель Ftp но иногда случается что она появляется слева. И вот тогда бывает что происходит большая проблема.
Вместо того что бы на хостинг записать последнюю версию моего проекта, получается так что с хостинга я перезаписываю на локальный компьютер старую версию. И все мои новые изменения в проекте затираются.
Это очень неудобно.

Есть ли какая-то возможность сделать так что бы Ftp панель всегда загружалась справа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение!
Достаточно зайти в настройки и указать панель в которой открывать Ftp соединение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+U поменять панели местами еще с Norton Commander.